# Javascript change plain text with input

Tags: javascript, onclick, edit, dynamically-generated, createelement

I want to replace contents of a clicked "td" element with input data and a button element.

When I click the "td" containing plain text, I want to swap the plain text with input (from elsewhere) and a button. When the button is clicked the input and button should be replaced with the plaintext of the input.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/a2y9s424/1/

***Note: I need to do that just using JAVASCRIPT, not jQuery***

```
function edit(td){


 if(isEdit==0)  { 
    data=td.value;
    isEdit=1;
satir=td.getAttribute("satir");
sutun=td.getAttribute("sutun");

 ilkDeger=td.innerHTML;

 myInput=document.createElement("input");
td.appendChild(myInput);
myInput.focus();

 kaydet=document.createElement("input");
kaydet.type="button";
 vazgec=document.createElement("input");
vazgec.type="button";

kaydet.value="Kaydet";


vazgec.value="Vazgeç";

td.appendChild(kaydet);
  td.appendChild(vazgec);



 }

 myInput.addEventListener("onblur",function(){
    blur=1;
});

vazgec.addEventListener("click",function(){

        td.innerHTML=ilkDeger;
        td.removeChild(kaydet);

        isEdit=0;
        return  false;



});
 kaydet.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("dsa");
    td.value="myInput.value;";

 });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach.

---

Attach a single click handler to the table instead of each cell.  You can do so by using `onclick` within the HTML, but it's usually preferable to keep your JavaScript and HTML separate:

```
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  ...
}
```

---

Within the handler, determine what was clicked using [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```
var o= evt.target;
```

---

Test if a `td` was clicked like this:

```
if(o.tagName==='TD') {
  ...
}
```

Note that `element.tagName` is always in uppercase.

---

If a `td` was clicked, save its `innerHTML` as an attribute, and replace its `innerHTML` with an `input`, `save` button, and `cancel` button.  Then set focus on the `input`:

```
if(o.tagName==='TD') {
  o.setAttribute('value', o.innerHTML);
  o.innerHTML= '<input type="text" value="'+o.innerHTML+'">' +
               '<button class="save"  >Save  </button>' +
               '<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>';

  o.querySelector('input').focus();
}
```

Note that I assigned classes (`save` and `cancel`) to the buttons.

---

Now we simply need the logic for the buttons, which we will add to the `table`'s click handler:

```
else if(o.className==='save') {
  o.parentNode.innerHTML= o.parentNode.querySelector('input').value;
}
else if(o.className==='cancel') {
  o.parentNode.innerHTML= o.parentNode.getAttribute('value');
}
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var o= evt.target;

  if(o.tagName==='TD') {
    o.setAttribute('value', o.innerHTML);
    o.innerHTML= '<input type="text" value="'+o.innerHTML+'">' +
                 '<button class="save"  >Save  </button>' +
                 '<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>';

    o.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
  else if(o.className==='save') {
    o.parentNode.innerHTML= o.parentNode.querySelector('input').value;
  }
  else if(o.className==='cancel') {
    o.parentNode.innerHTML= o.parentNode.getAttribute('value');
  }
});
```

---

Note that there are no local variables.  Also, there's no need to use `createElement` or `appendChild`, because that's handled by using `innerHTML`.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dqb9zdaq/)

Comment: idk but this works fine with plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lkq6RFqcyjSNS57DdcUx?p=info)

Comment: I think he wants the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons to disappear when clicked, and to change (or not change) the table content.

Comment: yea, i know the solution you gave is totally perfect but still i am wondering why this code works on plunker instead on Jsfiddle.

Comment: Gotcha.  You can't have inline JavaScript in JSFiddle unless you use the `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>` options.  It works here:  https://jsfiddle.net/xyrLLtup/

Comment: ahh thanks :), i hope next time i'll be more cautious.

Comment: @RickHitchcock that's great.Thank you so much.I changed a bit.It is possible for editing at the same time here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/dqb9zdaq/3/   Note:I have not enough rep to vote,sorry

Comment: That's a good improvement.  Your question is good, so I voted it up.